# Error while using datetime with a variable

Tags: shell, date

This is the code that I want to execute -

```
p=10
time1=`date --date='now + ($p) min' +%s`
current_time=`date +%s`
minutes=`echo $((p-current_time)) | awk '{print int($1/60)}'`
```

However the minutes difference is always 1. It doesn't take $p into account.
When I do -

```
time1=`date --date='now + 10 min' +%s`
```

the output is 10 minutes. How can I specify a variable there?

Comment: There could be another way to achieve result if you could describe what are you trying to achieve. It is not clear from your explanation.

Comment: I want to set the value of time1 to current time + p, so that I can use it later in my code.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> time1=`date --date='now + ($p) min' +%s`
> ```

The `$p` is not expanded due to the use of [single-quotes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_02):

> Enclosing characters in single-quotes ( '' ) shall preserve the literal value of each character within the
>   single-quotes.

Also, we cannot use the parentheses around `$p`. Correct:

```
time1=`date --date="now + $p min" +%s`
```